# Sorting the smallest K elements of a vector to implement a brute-force K-nearest neighbor algorithm on GPU

Tags: sorting, cuda, gpu, thrust, knn

I have implemented a *K*-nearest neighbor on the GPU using both pure CUDA and Thrust library function calls.

Euclidean distances are computed with a pure CUDA kernel. Then, Thrust sorting facilities (radix sort) are used to sort the distances in increasing order. Finally, the *K* first elements (i.e. the *K* nearest neighbors) are retrieved from the sorted vectors.

My implementation works well. However, sorting the entire euclidean distances matrix (sets can contain more than `250000` train samples) just to retrieve the *K*-nn seems non-optimal.

Therefore, I'm searching for a GPU algorithm implementation which allows to stop the sorting computations once the *K* smallest elements are found, or which performs an efficient *K* out of *N* sorting. It would indeed be faster for small *K* than sorting the entire matrix.

If such an implementation is not available, I would also be interested by advices to implement it efficiently in pure CUDA or Thrust. I was thinking to use a few threads per test samples to look for *K* nearest, each thread running to a part of the euclidean distances. I would maintain a buffer of size *K* in shared memory. I would run through the distances and insert the Knn in the shared memory vector. However, it would require some warp level synchronization and thread divergence.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Questions asking to recommend or find a library are off-topic for StackOverflow. However, it seems to me that you would better need an approach, rather than a library. You may wish to reformulate your question accordingly. As long as I know, K-nearest neighbors is effectively solved by KD-trees approaches, see for example [Proj 12 GPU Nearest Neighbors using a Minimal kd-tree](https://sites.google.com/a/nirmauni.ac.in/cudacodes/cuda-projects/proj-12-gpu-nearest-neighbors-using-a-minimal-kd-tree).

Comment: @JackOLantern thank you for you answer. However, my goal is to implement the "brute force" KNN algorithm on GPU, not the kd-tree version. You are right, question asking to recommend a library are off-topic, therefore I modified my question. I hope it is fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeking an approach for the *K*-nearest neighbor problem consisting of two steps:

1. Finding the Euclidean distances between the elements;
2. Finding the first `K` elements providing the `K` smallest distances.

It seems that such an approach is already existing and has been implemented in

[K.Kato and T.Hosino, "Solving *k*-Nearest Neighbor Problem on Multiple Graphics Processors"](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0906.0231.pdf)

and presented at the 2009 GTC Conference as

[K.Kato and T.Hosino, "You Might Also Like: A Multi-GPU Recommendation System"](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2009/presentations/1034-Multi-GPU-Recommendation-System.pdf).

The approach solves the above two steps by

1. using the classical *N*-body approach developed in L.Nyland, M.Harris, J.Prins, "Fast *N*-body simulation with CUDA," In: GPU Gems III. NVIDIA (2007) 677–695 to calculate the Euclidean distances;
2. using the [partial sorting](http://www.lsi.upc.edu/~conrado/research/talks/aofa04.pdf) technique, based on a parallel heapsort idea.

Again, as mentioned in my comment above, a better approach avoiding your "brute-force" one would be to use [KD-trees](https://sites.google.com/a/nirmauni.ac.in/cudacodes/cuda-projects/proj-12-gpu-nearest-neighbors-using-a-minimal-kd-tree).

Comment: Thank you @JackOLantern it's exactly what I was looking for. These scientific papers are useful. I was only relying on http://www.academypublisher.com/proc/iscsct09/papers/iscsct09p151.pdf  but it seems like yours present smarter ideas.